# Mocha API testing with Typescript async

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am using Typescript, working with Mocha and trying to use ES6 async/await generators.

Here's my code:

```
"use strict";
import * as console from 'console';
import { Config } from './Config';
import * as assert from 'assert';
import * as mocha from 'mocha';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function createExchangeRate(date: string) {
  let body = JSON.stringify({
    'ts': date,
    'gbptoUSD': 1.0,
    'eurtoUSD': 1.0,
    'cyntoUSD': 1.0
  });
  return fetch(`${Config.host()}/exchangeRate`, { method: 'POST', body: body });
}

describe('/exchangeRate', function() {

  let date = '2016-01-01';

  it('creates the exchange rate', async function(done) {
    let response = await createExchangeRate(date);
    console.log('Got my promise!');
    let body = await response.json();
    assert.equal(response.status, 204);
    assert.ok(body.uuid);
    done();
  });

});
```

Everything compiles correctly however the promise returned by `createExchangeRate` never seems to be resolved and the `console.log` is never reached.

Eventually the Mocha test times out and I get a message similar to:

> Error: timeout of 5000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being
>   called in this test.

I've tried a range of different formats but can't see where I'm going wrong...

**UPDATE**

If I refactor my test to remove the async/await keywords, it works:

```
it('creates the exchange rate', () => {
  createExchangeRate(date).then(function(response) {
    expect(response.status).to.equal(204);
    response.json().then(function(body) {
      expect(body.uuid).to.be.ok;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try just running your test code as a plain function outside Mocha? *If* you can replicate the same behavior without Mocha, that's immensely useful. For one thing, you can focus your attention on where the problem can actually be (not Mocha). Secondly, you could rewrite your question here to eliminate Mocha, which would help make your question read by a wider audience. People tend to skip questions tagged with technologies they don't know. The more diverse the tags on a question, the smaller the set of potential readers.

Comment: Is it possible that your function createExchangeRate takes more than default timeout? Please remember that timeout includes initialization code as well (so it's not only purely your code execution). To start with, you could try increasing timeout by adding `this.timeout = someValue` before your `await` code.

Comment: I've tried adding a timeout of 30 seconds which didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` on `createExchangeRate` isn't necessary (although I don't think it actually hurts). The async keyword allows you to use `await` (which you're not) and makes your function return a promise (which you're already doing when you return `fetch()`).

Also, your extra test after refactoring doesn't work! It does some async operations, but doesn't wait for the response. Mocha doesn't know anything about the promise unless you tell it about it, so as soon as createExchangeRate returns (i.e. immediately, before the request comes back) Mocha thinks your test is successful. If you return the promises at each stage (`return createExchangeRate(...` and `return response.json(...`) then it'll do what you expect.

More importantly, you're mixing two ways of handling async in mocha, with both `done` and promises. If you add a done parameter, Mocha waits until you call it. If you return a promise, Mocha waits until that promise resolves. You want to do only one of these, and I think it's plausible that trying to do both is causing you some of the problems here.

If you don't include the done parameter, and your test returns a promise (as async functions do automatically) everything will probably work. Personally, I'd write your test as:

```
describe('/exchangeRate', function() {
  let date = '2016-01-01';

  it('creates the exchange rate', async function() {
    let response = await createExchangeRate(date);
    console.log('Got my promise!');
    let body = await response.json();
    assert.equal(response.status, 204);
    assert.ok(body.uuid);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `createExchangeRate` doesn't have an `await` keyword inside. Therefore, this function is not `async`. Remove `async` keyword before it, and it should work fine.